# sum total if over certain days old aws disk size in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

cannot get the sum total of volumes if days are older than certain value Example 20, keeps returning exception

Trying to total up total disks size within python script if `age = 20`, can print the values when found , cannot sum the total disks found by their size `if days_old > age`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
import datetime

age = 20

def days_old(date):
    date_obj = date.replace(tzinfo=None)
    diff = datetime.datetime.now() - date_obj
    return diff.days

# datetime.datetime.now() to get  
# current date as filename. 
Available_Volumes = datetime.datetime.now()

# open a (new) file to write
outF = open("Available_Volumes_"+Available_Volumes.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H:%M")+".txt", "a")

#for lambda use def lambda_handler(object, context):
def main():

    # Get list of regions
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    regions = [region['RegionName']
               for region in ec2_client.describe_regions()['Regions']]

    for region in regions:
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)
        print(("Region:", region))

        # List only unattached volumes ('available' vs. 'in-use')
        volumes = ec2.volumes.filter(
            Filters=[{'Name': 'status', 'Values': ['available']}])
        for volume in volumes:
            v = ec2.Volume(volume.id)
            create_date = (v.create_time)
            day_old = days_old(create_date)
            if day_old > age:
                try:
                    outF.write("Found Available Volume that is {} days old !! Deleting EBS volume: {}, Size: {} GiB\n".format(day_old, v.id, v.size))
                    print (v.id)
                    print ("Size of Volume is ",v.size)
                    print ("Number of Days old is equal to {} ".format(day_old))
                    print("Found Available Volume that is {} days old Deleting EBS volume: {}, Size: {} GiB\n".format(day_old, v.id, v.size))
                    #unhash to allow delete
                    #v.delete()
                except:
                    print ("can't delete")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# Copy to S3 Bucket
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file("Available_Volumes_"+Available_Volumes.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H:%M")+".txt", 'mybucket', "Available_Volumes_"+Available_Volumes.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H:%M")+".txt")
```

keep getting the except error can't delete

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you should remove `try/except` to see full exception message or at least uses `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: What is the _specific_ problem that you are experiencing? Also, can you show all of your code? For example, what is `age`, `days_old()` and `outF`? Plus, the indents are incorrect.

Comment: I have updated with full code, when I try to sum v.size if days_old > age I get the except ("can't delete") outF adds the correct outputs to file minus the totals. for this particular query days_old > age only returns 3 volumes

Comment: still unable to sum the totals of only values found in a date

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `size` value like this:

```py
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
volumes = ec2.volumes.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'status', 'Values': ['available']}])

totalsize = 0
for volume in volumes:
    totalsize += volume.size

print(totalsize)
```

Or, the more Pythonic method:

```py
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
volumes = ec2.volumes.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'status', 'Values': ['available']}])

print(sum(volume.size for volume in volumes))
```

Comment: This ignores the if days old which is all that should be reported (summed) it sums on the total volumes in region ignoring the if days_old. I tested on value of 50 days and available which has total volume in single region of 80GB available, this returns 740GB which is total of all available in region. I am trying to total (sum) only if 20 days old.

Comment: That is correct. I am simply demonstrating how you can total the volume size, which appears to be your question.

Comment: sorry, ill edit and update the question to reflect correctly